# function javascript

Tags: javascript, funções

Define a função hojeSeJoga, que receba por parâmetro uma string que informe o día da semana. Esta função deve retornar"Hoje é dia de futebol!!!" se parâmetro for "domingo", caso contrário deve retornar "Hoje não é dia de futebol :(".

```
function hojeSeJoga(diaDaSemana) {
if (diaDaSemana === "domingo") {
    return 'Hoje é dia de futebol!!!';
} else {
    return 'Hoje não é dia de futebol'
}
```

}

Pessoal essa formula esta dando erro vcs podem me ajudar!

Comment: A pergunta continua muito mal formulada. Como você chama a função pra testar?  Como é o valor do parâmetro diaDaSemana - numérico, string, data...? Você notou que está comparando uma variável com ela mesma (hojeSeJoga == hojeSeJoga)? Você notou que essa variável é o próprio nome da função, e portanto ela não pode conter o nome de um dia?

Answer (score 1):

Você estava comparando errado as informações. Você deve comparar com o parâmetro e não com o nome da função

```
function hojeSeJoga(diaDaSemana) {
    if (diaDaSemana === "domingo") {
        return 'Hoje é dia de futebol!!!';
    } else {
        return 'Hoje não é dia de futebol'
    }
}
```

Comment: Oi  Douglas mesmo assim aparece esse erro:   Sua solução não passou as provas
Objetivos que não foram atendidos:
 hojeSeJoga faz comparações contra strings
Resultados do teste:
 hojeSeJoga("domingo") deveria dizer se joga
 hojeSeJoga("terça") devería dizer que não joga

Comment: Marcos, seu problema não foi bem descrito. Acredito que você está passando essa função em alguma ferramenta que verifica se o código está correto. De acordo com o que você descreveu agora, me parece que você está retornando as frases erradas ali dentro do "return". Tente alterar as frases retornadas, talvez esse seja o problema.