# Alguém poderia me ajudar com um exercício de JS? CONDICIONAIS

Tags: javascript, if, return, else

Gente, ajuda aqui, por favor! Eu preciso fazer esse código dar certo.  Eu já tentei de tudo e continua dando erro. Como vcs fariam?

Define a função hojeSeJoga, que receba por parâmetro uma string que informe o dia da semana. Esta função deve retornar "Hoje é dia de futebol!!!" se parâmetro for "domingo", caso contrário deve retornar "Hoje não é dia de futebol :(".

Comment: Para entender melhor o funcionamento do StackOverflow em português leia: [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70).

Comment: Essa questão já foi feita [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/424053/ajuda-com-erro-compara%c3%a7%c3%b5es-contra-strings),[aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422587/retornando-falso-com-else-em-javascript), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/423312/javascript-function), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/423561/function-javascript), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422514/atividade-condicional-em-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

É meio confuso esse exercício e essa pergunta já foi respondida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/424053/ajuda-com-erro-compara%C3%A7%C3%B5es-contra-strings), mais vamos lá...

Para o código não ficar com diversas váriaveis você pode fazer assim:

```
var semana = ['Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado', 'Domingo']; // Defini um array com todos os dias da semana
function hojeseJoga(s) { // Parâmetro any, não possui nenhum tipo de verificação, mas caso queira, pode usar o typeof e fazer uma validação se é string ou não, vai do seu critério
    if(s == semana.slice(6, 7)) { // Aqui compara o parâmetro com a função slice, que ele faz uma copia do array original e indica o começo e o fim onde deseja copiar
        console.log("Hoje é dia de futebol");
    } else {
        console.log("Hoje não é dia de futebol");
    }
}
hojeseJoga("Terça"); // Retorno: Hoje não é dia de futebol
hojeseJoga("Domingo"); // Retorno: Hoje é dia de futebol
```

Caso não queira usar [array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array) pode usar uma variável simples também:

```
var domingo = "Domingo";

function hojeseJoga(s) {
    if(s == domingo) {
        console.log("Hoje é dia de futebol");
    } else {
        console.log("Hoje não é dia de futebol");
    }
}
hojeseJoga("Terça"); // Hoje não é dia de futebol;
hojeseJoga("Domingo"); //Hoje é dia de futebol
```

Lembrando que a função é [case-sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity), então se passar `hojeseJoga("domingo")` retornará o bloco do `else`.
Existem diversas formas para fazer, o melhor é quanto você mais fazer e mais soluções tiver :D